# How can I set the Source property of a FFImageLoading.SvgCachedImage from a Dynamic Resource in a Xamarin C# view?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is is the XAMLcode I am currently using:

```
<ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage  Source="{DynamicResource GearIcon}" />
```

GearIcon is set to "Test.Resources.Theme.gear_light.svg" and everything works perfectly. When I set the Dynamic Resource to "Test.Resources.Theme.gear_dark.svg" then the image changes as expected.

Now I am trying to change this to use fluent C# but nothing is working when I do this:

```
var gear = new SvgCachedImage;
gear.DynamicResource(SourceProperty, SvgImageSource.FromResource(Application.Current.Resources["GearIcon"].ToString()));
```

I have also tried this:

```
gear.DynamicResource(SourceProperty, (Application.Current.Resources["GearIcon"].ToString()));
```

and

```
gear.DynamicResource(SourceProperty, (ImageSource)(Application.Current.Resources["GearIcon"].ToString()));
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can set the source dynamically when using C#.  Nothing I have tried works so far except the XAML which I am not using right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
using FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;

SvgCachedImage gear = this.GetTemplateChild("YOUR SVGCACHEDIMAGE NAME ON YOUR XAML PAGE") as SvgCachedImage;

gear.source = SvgImageSource.FromResource("YOUR ROOT FOLDER NAME.YOUR IMAGE FOLDER NAME.GearIcon.svg");
```

Comment: Make sure the image is an  EMBEDDED RESOURCE

Answer (score 0):

The type of `Source` in **SvgCachedImage** is a ImageSource . So if you want to set it in code behind you could call the following line .

```
gear.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(Application.Current.Resources["GearIcon"].ToString());
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply.  Please note my svgs are embedded resources so I think it will not work if you use "FromFile".   

Unfortunately your suggestion doesn't show the svg image and also it need to change the image when the resource is changed between: Test.Resources.Theme.gear_light.svg and Test.Resources.Theme.gear_dark.svg.  dynamically.

Comment: Could you share a sample so that I can test it on my side ?

Comment: Could you share a sample so that I can test it on my side ?  In addition , why don't you define the source of image in ViewModel and binding it to the SvgCachedImage  ? In this way you just need to set the binding source .'